# Does docker allow for robotic process automation?

Tags: docker, ui-automation, blueprism, rpa, uipath

Can docker containers be used along with UI based RPA tools like blueprism or uiPath? Blueprism recommends using virtual machines but offers no support of docker

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will be possible. I'm unfamiliar with the solutions you describe so I'm unable to provide you with specific examples.

**Any** Linux (and Windows) process can be run in a container.

Docker made containers into a *thing* but they're really not. They're just (very useful) conceptual "sugar" on Linux namespaces and cgroups to make the functionality more accessible. They provide a way to segregate e.g. one or more Linux processes (and their resources).

So, unless someone else has done the "containerization" already (likely), you should be able to do this reasonably easily for yourself. The primary challenge will be in relaxing the container boundary to access machine or other process resources.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that Kofax RPA is fully supported on Docker (and Kubernetes)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, containerization is possible for BP server. But not for client/resource as it requires terminal session to run the desktop applications.