# Install Blue Prism Application Server inside Docker container

Tags: docker, blueprism

I'm planning to deploy BluePrism infrastructure using multi-device deployment approach. There is one important consern. BluePrism will operate very sensetive information so it is strictly required to maximum secure it.

So I consider to use Docker container for server deployment. Docker container provides fully managed environment. Docker also make it much more difficult to install unwanted third party software on server.

So question is, is it possible to install Blue Prism App server into Docker container?

Comment: What is wrong with question? Why down voting?

Answer (score 4):

If `Blue Prism` runs on `linux` or even `windows` OS, then its possible to run inside docker.

Check [this](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) out to know how to containerize any application.

Lot of peoples create there own docker image of there application and put them on public docker repository like [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/). But I don't find any image for blue prism there, so creating your own image from scratch seems to be a solution.

I also found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937663/does-docker-allow-for-robotic-process-automation), but it seems creating image from scratch is the solution.